# Determine the Galois group of $x^4 -4x^2+2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

**Determine the Galois group of  $x^4 -4x^2+2$**

After discussing with some classmates , two approaches arised  yielding different answers, so at least one should be wrong:

The roots are $\pm \alpha=\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2} $ ;  $\pm \beta=\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}$

**Approach 1**

Since $\sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q (\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2})$ because $\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}^2-2=2 $

Also $(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2} \in \Bbb Q (\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2})$ because $\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}= \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}  } $

Since there are four possibilities for an automorphism $\sigma :\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2} \mapsto: \sigma(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2})$ which are each of the four roots and  $(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}$ is already determined after this choice, the Galois group is isomorphic to a group with 4 elements

**Approach 2**

Using the tower rule

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \Bbb Q(\alpha)][\Bbb Q(\alpha) : \Bbb Q]$.

$[\Bbb Q(\alpha) : \Bbb Q]=$4 , as the polinomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$

On another hand: $\beta=4-\alpha^2$ so the minimum polynomial of beta $m_{\beta}| (x^2+\alpha^2-4)$

$\alpha^2-4=\sqrt 2 -2 $ so if $(x^2+\alpha^2-4)$ splits , then it has zeros $\pm \sqrt{2-\sqrt 2} $ which are not in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ so $[\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \Bbb Q(\alpha)]=2$

and  $[\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta) : \Bbb Q]=8 $.Then the Galois group is isomorphic to $\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle$ defined as $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta$, $\sigma(\beta)=-\alpha$, $\tau(\alpha)=-\alpha, \tau (\beta)= \beta$ which has order 8

**I think approach one is the correct one, but how do I determine what order-4 group is the galois group isomorphic to?**

Edit:

Following with approach 1 and the suggestion in the comments:

For the case

1. $\sigma( \alpha)=\beta$

I have that  $\sigma( \sqrt 2)=\sigma(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}^2)-\sigma(2)=(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}^2)-2=-\sqrt 2$

Then  $\sigma( \beta)=\sigma(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2})=\frac{\sigma(\sqrt 2)}{\sigma(\sqrt {2+\sqrt 2})}=\frac{-(\sqrt 2)}{\sqrt {2-\sqrt 2}}=- \sqrt {2+\sqrt 2}=-\alpha$

so $\sigma^2(\alpha)=\sigma(\beta)=-\alpha$

Similarly with the other cases:

2. $\sigma( \alpha)=-\beta$

I get  $\sigma( \beta)=\alpha$ and $\sigma^2(\alpha)=\sigma(-\beta)=-\alpha$

3. $\sigma( \alpha)=\alpha$

I get  $\sigma( \beta)=\beta$ and $\sigma^2(\alpha)=\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$

4. $\sigma( \alpha)=-\alpha$

I get  $\sigma( \beta)=-\beta$ and $\sigma^2(\alpha)=\sigma(-\alpha)=\alpha$

How does this help to get to the answer?

Comment: In Approach 1 you say $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}$. In Approach 2 you say the opposite.

Comment: Also, in Approach 1, your reasoning satisfactorialy demonstrates that $|G| \le 4$, but why is $|G| = 4$, and why is $G \cong C_4$?

Comment: Does it mean $[Q(\alpha, \beta) : \Bbb Q(\alpha)]=2$ is wrong according to approach 2 and it should be 1?

Comment: How do I determine that the group has exactly 4 elements and which order-4 group it is isomorphic to?

Comment: Approach 2 is certainly wrong since the calculation in App 1 shows that $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and so the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. You know the four possible images of $\alpha$ so you just have to calculate whether all square to the identity or not.  It may - or may not - help you to realise this is not a random polynomial, it is $(X^2-2)^2-2$, and the roots are $2\cos (2\pi/16)$ and its friends.

Comment: @ancientmathematician  Sorry I don't understand what you mean with"...calculate whether all square to the identity or not" Do you mean determine if the square of each image of alpha  is 0 or not? They are obviously not zero. Did you mean the sum, which is zero because is -the degree 3 term in the polynomial? Also the images of alpha are just the other roots. Furthermore I don't know what is the connection of this with determining what 4 element group is the galois group

Comment: Sorry!  I meant for each of your 4 automorphisms $\sigma$ determine whether $\sigma^2(\alpha)=\alpha$. That will tell you which group of order $4$ it is. Sorry again.

Comment: @ancientmathematician  Please see my edit, I followed your suggestion, but I really don't see how one uses this to decide the group

Comment: Well in case 1 (if your sums are correct) you've found an element of order $4$ haven't you? That decides the matter.

Comment: @ancientmathematician So i learned that what decides the matter is to check in which of the two possible 4-order subgroups I have elements an element of order 4 correct? If by any chance both option had one, I would have to look at the order of some other element in my group and look if there's a matching element with that order in the two possibilities, etc. So at the end I need that the 4 elements have orders that match those of the 4 elements in the group I am trying to prove it is  isomorphism to.

Comment: You can't generalise like this. This is specific to $4$. Everyone knows (or ought to) that there are two groups of order $4$: the cyclic one $C_4$ and the Klein fours-group $C_2\times C_2.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yeah, I meant for any other (finite )order, first I have to know what are all the groups of that order and then look at the individual orders of the elements to match the group to one of the standard groups that has elements with those orders. Correct? For infinite order, I don't know

Comment: When I calculate Galois Groups that's not how I do it. The group permutes the roots of the polynomial in question. So, e.g., if I were looking at a quartic equation and I knew the order of the group was $12$ I wouldn't start looking at the $5$(?) possible groups of order $12$ I'd only look at subgroups of order $12$ of $S_4$ and see at once I had $A_4$.  But the system is rebuking us for this exchange, so I will now stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to leave this as a comment but don't have enough reputation, I wanted to suggest a useful resource: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/galois/lastyear/Galois.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Etl/galois/lastyear/Galois.pdf) on page 60, which proves the following theorem:

Let $f(X) = X^4+aX^2+b \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be irreducible.

(i) If $b$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\text{Gal} (\mathbb{Q}(f(X))/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2 \times \mathbb{Z} /2$.

(ii) If $b(a^2-4b)$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\text{Gal} (\mathbb{Q}(f(X))/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 4$.

(iii) If neither $b$ nor $b(a^2-4b)$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\text{Gal} (\mathbb{Q}(f(X))/\mathbb{Q}) \cong D_8$.